# Find resources dynamically loading and change or add to the url

Tags: functions, customization

Is there a way using the wordpress functions.php file that I can:

Find a resource trying to load from a url and add to it or change it.

For example, if a .woff file was loading dynamically from a plugin or theme, i could identify it by the .woff file extension in the url and add to it and make it end in .woff&example=hello

So all url's that are being called ending in .woff get &hello=example added to the end?